# How to compare two integer values with text?

Tags: protractor

HTML code:

```
<li class="list-group-item ng-binding ng-scope" ng-repeat="sourceMatch in sourceMatches">
   <img ng-src="/static/images/Timesjobs_small.jpg" width="32px" height="32px">
   <span class="badge ng-binding">585784</span>
   Times Jobs
</li>
```

I am getting this error.

```
Expected '52675
Times Jobs' to match '52619 Times Jobs'.
```

It is showing integer value in first line and text in second line so that am not able to compare. How to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

getText() always returns string, but you have line break there, try to replace /n/r before comparing

```
var listItemText = $(li.list-group-item).getText()
    .then(function(text){ return text.replace(/[\r\n]/g, "")

expect(listItemText).toMatch('52619 Times Jobs')
```

Comment: I tried like this but it's not working : var listItemText = element.all(by.css("li.list-group-item")).get(0).getText().then(function(text){text.replace('\n\r', '')
            return text})

        expect(listItemText).toMatch('52619 Times Jobs')

Comment: Your number is different - make sure that you comparing with the right string:
52675
52619

Comment: It's working, i just changed ur code text.replace('\n\r', '')) to text.replace(/\n/g, ""). Thanks